# mysql procedure not update table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, save, sql-insert, procedure

I need to sort through all the products and save the data on them in a separate table, if there are any - an update, if not - a new record. I wrote a procedure for sorting goods. if I output variables with a separate one, then everything works, but the data is not saved. how to fix it?
in finish write error

> No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

there are no updates in the row.
What did I do wrong?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateProduct()
BEGIN
DECLARE done int DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE counter int;
    DECLARE var_product_id int;
    DECLARE var_isset_product_id int;
    DECLARE var_last_day int;

    DECLARE ps_rating float;
    DECLARE ps_comment int;
    DECLARE ps_price_discount int;
    DECLARE ps_price_average int;
    DECLARE ps_quantity int;
    DECLARE ps_lost_sale int;
    DECLARE ps_order30 int;
    DECLARE ps_revenue30 int;
    DECLARE ps_order30pre int;
    DECLARE ps_revenue30pre int;

    DECLARE var_cur CURSOR FOR select distinct id from product p order by id limit 100000 ;

    OPEN var_cur;

    read_loop:
    LOOP
        FETCH var_cur INTO var_product_id;
        IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;

        # ID ТОВАРА
        SELECT `product_id`
        INTO var_isset_product_id
        FROM `product_summary`
        WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id;

        # ДАТА ПОСЛЕДНЕГО ЛОГА
        SELECT max(`create_at`)
        INTO var_last_day
        FROM `product_log`
        WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
          AND `create_at` <= unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day);

        IF var_last_day IS NOT NULL THEN

            # РЕЙТИНГ
            SELECT COALESCE(`rating`, 0)
            INTO ps_rating
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` = var_last_day;

            # КОЛИЧЕСТВО КОММЕНТАРИЕВ
            SELECT COALESCE(`comment`, 0)
            INTO ps_comment
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` = var_last_day;

            # ЦЕНА СО СКИДКОЙ
            SELECT COALESCE(`price_discount`, 0)
            INTO ps_price_discount
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` = var_last_day;

            # СРЕДНЯЯ ЦЕНА СО СКИДКОЙ ЗА 30 ДНЕЙ
            SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(avg(`price_discount`)), 0)
            INTO ps_price_average
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND create_at BETWEEN unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 31 day) and unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day);

            # КОЛ-ВО ОСТАТКОВ
            SELECT COALESCE(`quantity`, 0)
            INTO ps_quantity
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` = var_last_day;

            # УПУЩЕННАЯ ВЫРУЧКА
            SELECT COALESCE(`lost_sale`, 0)
            INTO ps_lost_sale
            FROM `product`
            WHERE `id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` = var_last_day;

            # КОЛ-ВО ЗАКАЗОВ ЗА 30 ДНЕЙ
            SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(`order_count`)), 0)
            INTO ps_order30
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` BETWEEN unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 31 day) and unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day);

            # ВЫРУЧКА ЗА 30 ДНЕЙ
            SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(`order_count` * `price_discount`)), 0)
            INTO ps_revenue30
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` BETWEEN unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 31 day) and unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 1 day);

            # КОЛ-ВО ЗАКАЗОВ ЗА ПРЕДЫДУЩИЕ 30 ДНЕЙ
            SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(`order_count`)), 0)
            INTO ps_order30pre
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` BETWEEN unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 62 day) and unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 32 day);

            # ВЫРУЧКА ЗА ПРЕДЫДУЩИЕ 30 ДНЕЙ
            SELECT COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(`order_count` * `price_discount`)), 0)
            INTO ps_revenue30pre
            FROM `product_log`
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id
              AND `create_at` BETWEEN unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 62 day) and unix_timestamp(curdate() - interval 32 day);


        IF var_isset_product_id IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE `product_summary`
            SET `rating`         = ps_rating,
                `comment`        = ps_comment,
                `price_discount` = ps_price_discount,
                `price_average`  = ps_price_average,
                `quantity`       = ps_quantity,
                `lost_sale`      = ps_lost_sale,
                `order30`        = ps_order30,
                `revenue30`      = ps_revenue30,
                `order30pre`     = ps_order30pre,
                `revenue30pre`   = ps_revenue30pre
            WHERE `product_id` = var_product_id;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO product_summary
            SET `rating`         = ps_rating,
                `comment`        = ps_comment,
                `price_discount` = ps_price_discount,
                `price_average`  = ps_price_average,
                `quantity`       = ps_quantity,
                `lost_sale`      = ps_lost_sale,
                `order30`        = ps_order30,
                `revenue30`      = ps_revenue30,
                `order30pre`     = ps_order30pre,
                `revenue30pre`   = ps_revenue30pre;
        END IF;

    END IF;

    set counter = counter + 1;

    end loop;

    CLOSE var_cur;

    select counter;

ND //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You haven't declared a handler..Also please add sample data as text together with table definitions.

Comment: Your primary error is the cursor is not populated - do you get anything when select distinct id from product p order by id limit 100000  ?

Comment: As for style you could cut down on the multiple reads from product_log by using the 'SELECT ... INTO var_list selects column values and stores them into variables'. version of select into ie many column into many variables https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html. Also I suspect you could do this without a procedure or cursor using  insert.. on.. duplicate key update https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html